# Render views row manually

Tags: views, theming

I need to take a view result, check all the row and render only some of it;

I found this code

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->execute('block_1');
$view->preview();

$renderer = $view->style_plugin->row_plugin;
foreach ($view->result as $index => $row) {
  $view->row_index = $index;
  echo $renderer->render($row);
}
```

but I changed it in:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->execute('block_1');
$view->preview();

$renderer = $view->style_plugin;

foreach ($view->result as $index => $field) {

  $full_line_item = commerce_line_item_load($field->field_commerce_line_items[0]['raw']['line_item_id']); 
  $data = unserialize($full_line_item->data);

  if(isset($data[0]) && $data[0] == 'ticket' && $data[2] == $content->nid){
    dsm($field);

    $view->row_index = $index;
    $output .=  $renderer->render($field);
  }
}

return $output;
```

But this code give me all the table rendered 2 times [the field the view have to render is two.. I don't know if this can be related.. ]

How can I solve this?